# Getting this error in findViewById() in the ImageView widget

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

This is my code of a dice roll app showing image dice 1 for now. The findViewById() is working fine with the textview but it's showing error with the image. This line

```kotlin
    val diceImage: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
```

The IDE is suggesting to create a function. How should I resolve it? I'm new to Kotlin and Android Studio.

```kotlin
package com.unnati.diceroll

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ImageView

/* these lines allows user to roll the dice and show on the screen */
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val rollButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
        rollButton.setOnClickListener {
            rollDice()
        }
    }  }
//roll the dice and show on the screen
    private fun rollDice() {
        val dice = Dice(6)
        val diceRoll = dice.roll()

        val diceImage: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
        diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_1)
}



class Dice(val numSides: Int) {
    fun roll(): Int {
        return (1..numSides).random()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write this line of code inside onCreate() method instead of rollDice() method

```
val diceImage: ImageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
```

edit the code like below

````
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

   lateinit var diceImage:ImageView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        diceImage = findViewById(R.id.imageView)
        val rollButton: Button = findViewById(R.id.button)
        rollButton.setOnClickListener {
            rollDice(diceImage)
        }
    }  }
//roll the dice and show on the screen
   private fun rollDice(diceImage: ImageView) {
        val dice = Dice(6)
        val diceRoll = dice.roll()
        diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_1)
}



class Dice(val numSides: Int) {
    fun roll(): Int {
        return (1..numSides).random()
    }
}```
````

Now findViewById() will work.

Comment: Now it's showing the error with line ```diceImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice_1)``` IDE is suggesting to create a function name 'diceImage'